# AutoHotkey - How to send a key that is not part of the current keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I use a program that uses <kbd>\</kbd> as a shortcut.

I use a French AZERTY keyboard, where the backslash can only be typed using a key combination: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>).

So I cannot activate the shortcut (unless I switch Windows to a US keyboard layout).

I thought AutoHotkey would be able to solve the issue, but remapping a key to backslash does not work as intended:

```
; TRY 1: using Send
*::
Send \
return

; TRY 2: simple remap
$::\
```

AutoHotkey actually sends the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>, so the shortcut is not triggered.

Is there any way for AutoHotkey to send the "real" <kbd>\</kbd> key, while keeping my AZERTY layout in Windows?

Comment: Try this example of mapping Ctrl-X to your key-sequence : `^x::send {Ctrl down} {Alt down} 8 {Alt up} {Ctrl up}`

Comment: @harrymc This does not work. A key sequence is not recognized by the program as a valid shortcut. Doing this manually does work either.

Comment: This worked for me, but may not solve your specific problem.

Comment: Try adding [SetKeyDelay](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetKeyDelay.htm) before the Send command or/and `SendEvent {LCtrl Down}{RAlt Down}8{LCtrl Up}{RAlt Up}`.